# How to return data to a function?

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following code:

```
MyFunction1(){
DoSomething (Value1);
}
MyFunction2(){
DoSomething(Value2);
}

DoSomething(int Amount) {
int i = Amount;

if (i > 1) {
i=0;
}

if (i>2) {
i=1;
}

if (i>=3){
i = 2;
}
etc ...
// how do I say i = Value; if I want to reuse this function to send Value1, Value2, Value3??
}
```

How can I reuse to function to send this back to the calling function?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you describe it in more detail? Also `if(i>2)` or `if(i>3)` will never execute because it will be handled by `if(i>1)`.

Comment: Conditions are just for example. The point is how do I pass different values into the same function which then changes and returns the same value

Comment: What is wrong with passing values as methods arguments? `myMethod(int myArgument){if(myArgument==1) doAction1();} if(myArgument==2) doAction2();}` Then you can use this method with `int x = 2; myMethod(x);`

Comment: Thanks for the input @Pshemo, that could be useful too

Comment: Well, judging from accepted answer method's argument was the thing you ware looking for :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're asking how to return a value from a function in Java. If I'm incorrect, disregard this response. When you declare the function `DoSomething`, you need to also declare the type of the return value of the function. In this case, you would probably use `int`, so the function would look more like:

```
int DoSomething(int Amount){
    int i = Amount;

    if (i=2){
        i = 1;
    }

    return i;
}
```

And to receive a value from this function, you need to assign it to a variable. So using your examples:

```
MyFunction1(){
    int answer;
    int Value2 = 2;

    answer = DoSomething(Value2);
}
```

If you could provide a more specific example of what you're trying to do, perhaps I could provide more help, but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the lack of clarity, I'm on my mobile... But it's just the question I have been wondering